# MonoTouch - simulator just quits

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, monodevelop

This is a fairly recent thing which appears to have happened after I downloaded and installed the latest xcode, I also went through some steps to acquire certificates/provisioning so I could deploy apps to an iPhone device (didn't finish with that, went back to coding), so either of those things could be related, I think I also updated monodevelop most recently.

The problem is basically: I run the simulator, the app loads up for a very short while then it exits. Before this the app was showing and when it crashed instead of showing where and how it crashed (callstack, etc) it would just exit the app.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning the build?

Also, are you compiling againts the lastest iOS SDK? See your project options :)

Answer (score 3):

iOs kills apps that take more than 10 seconds to comPlete FinishedLoading

Comment: It deifnitely is shuttong off before 10 seconds have passed, it's more like 2 seconds. I only load one 1024x1024 image as a texture and about 10 xml files, there isn't much loading up for it to take 10 seconds...